# How can I log 404s to ELMAH when using the NotFound MVC package?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, elmah

I've installed the [NotFound MVC Nuget package](https://nuget.org/packages/NotFoundMvc/) in a handful of ASP.NET MVC 4 websites.

However, I liked having a log of these errors in ELMAH so that I could easily pull everything about the clients that triggered 404s on my site.

For now I've added the following logic within the `NotFound` view:

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Request not found: " + ViewBag.RequestedUrl));
```

Is there a better way to continue to log 404s in ELMAH after installing NotFound MVC?

Comment: Can you show your code where you are registering the all the filters?  (ex.  `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());`)

Comment: `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` is the only one that's included. Note that NotFound MVC seems to add a catch-all route so it doesn't appear that an actual exception is ever triggered. See the readme on https://github.com/andrewdavey/notfoundmvc `Elmah.MVC` is being used, and without NotFound MVC 404s were getting caught by ELMAH as expected.

Comment: Can you post the part in the web.config using the NotFound MVC?

Comment: Here's what the package adds to the Web.config: https://github.com/andrewdavey/NotFoundMvc/blob/master/package/input/content/web.config.transform

Comment: IMO, based on the fact that the NotFound package is removing the 404 HttpStatusCode at the IIS level and replacing it with it's own custom code, you will need to integrate ELMAH into the NotFound package as you have done. The location you have integrated with seems to be a logical place.

Comment: @PaigeCook could you tell me how to integrate elmah into notfound mvc package?

Comment: @Willy - I have not actually integrated the two before. The approach that the OP did in the question seems correct, IMO.